# How to temporally shift the caption below tikzpicture (larger vertical spaces)

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

I just tried to draw a block diagram with `tikzpicture` using the `dsp` library. It all worked correctly until I tried to add the caption to it.

The problem is that the vertical space between the `tikzpicture` and the caption is too small:

[image: Caption get too close to picture]

Here is my source code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc, 
 numbers=noendperiod, abstracton, parskip=half, headsepline
 %, plainheadsepline
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,dsp,chains,calc}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\newcommand{\z}{\mathpzc{z}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m1) [row sep=15mm, column sep=20mm]
{
    %------------------------------------------
    \node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=above] (m00) {$x[n]$};    &
    \node[dspnodeopen]                 (m01) {};        &
    \node[dspnodeopen]                 (m02) {};        &
    \node[dspnodeopen]                 (m03) {};        &
    \node[dspnodeopen]                 (m04) {};        &
    \node[dspnodeopen]                 (m05) {};        \\
    %------------------------------------------
    \node[coordinate]                  (m10) {};        &
    \node[coordinate]                  (m11) {};        &
    \node[coordinate]                  (m12) {};        &
    \node[coordinate]                  (m13) {};        &
    \node[coordinate]                  (m14) {};        &
    \node[coordinate]                  (m15) {};  \\
    %------------------------------------------
    \node[coordinate]                  (m20) {};        &
    \node[coordinate]                  (m21) {};        &
    \node[coordinate]                  (m22) {};        &
    \node[coordinate]                  (m23) {};        &
    \node[coordinate]                  (m24) {};        &
    \node[coordinate]                  (m25) {};  \\
    %------------------------------------------
    \node[coordinate]                   (m30) {};        &
    \node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=below]  (m31) {$B[0]$};  &
    \node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=below]  (m32) {$B[1]$};  &
    \node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=below]  (m33) {$B[2]$};  &
    \node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=below]  (m34) {$B[3]$};  &
    \node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=below]  (m35) {$B[128]$};  \\
};

\draw[dspflow] (m00) -- (m01);

\foreach \i [evaluate = \i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {1,2,3}
    \draw[dspflow] (m0\i) -- node[midway,above] {$\z^{-1}$} (m0\j);

\path (m04) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (m05);

\foreach \i [evaluate = \i as \j using int(\i-1)] in {1,2,...,4}
    \draw[dspflow] (m0\i) -- node[midway,right] {$h[\j]$} (m1\i);
\draw[dspflow] (m05) --node[midway,right] {$h[128]$} (m15);

\draw ($(m11) - (2mm,0)$) rectangle node[midway] {128-Punkt FFT} ($(m25) + (2mm,0)$);

\foreach \i [evaluate = \i as \j using int(\i-1)] in {1,2,...,4}
    \draw[dspflow] (m2\i) --  (m3\i);
\draw[dspflow] (m25) -- (m35);

\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Blockschaltbild einer 128-Punkt FFT-Filterbank}
\label{fig:fft128}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please make your code compilable! add `\documentclas{...}` necessary preamble, and on the end `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your definition of `dsp/label` seems to be the culprit. Replacing `\node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=below] (<mxx>) {<text>};` with `\node[dspnodeopen,label={below:<text>}] (<mxx>) {};` fixed the problem. But without a complete MWE we can't help you any further.

Comment: have edited the source code, should be compilable. the solution with dsp/labe={below:text} dosen't solve the problem, when use that all text disapprear...

Comment: It can't be compiled without the library, which is not standard. `Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'dsp'.  ...`.

Comment: you can download dsp library here:http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/zip/tikz-dsp.zip

Comment: Please edit your question to attribute the code you've posted correctly. I take it is basically Matthias Hotz's example from http://texample.net/tikz/examples/fir-filter/ and/or Karlheinz Ochs's.

Comment: sry, forgot to delete [H], well, it is modified from that example, but the problem is the caption,and in that example no caption is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix: add `\medskip` between `\end{tikzpicture}` and `\caption`.

The reason is that the `B[N]` labels seem to not be considered for the bounding box of the `tikzpicture`. You can (as an alternative to `\medskip`) modify the bounding box manually, by adding

```
\useasboundingbox (current bounding box.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-2ex]current bounding box.south east);
```

right before `\end{tikzpicture}`.